# get current hard disk read write in ubuntu and make log file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, performance-monitoring

I'm writing a customized monitoring panel for Ubuntu server.

At this step i need to get real time hard disk read and write rate then put it into a file as a log file.

I used tools like Hdparm,Iotop but did not worked. I want result into a file.

I want some result like :

10Kb read - 2kb write - 2014-2-13 16:40:03

So i can run it as Crontab and monitor every I/O rate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
iostat /dev/sda \
          | grep 'sda' | awk  '{if ($2) print $2}' \
          | awk -v var="$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %r")" '{print  $1"&",var";"}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get this information from `/proc`. See how the munin `disk_*` plugins do it.